# Flutter unable to set state of list<object>

Tags: dart, flutter, state

Here is how the main `TodoApp` widget looks like:

```
class TodoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(title: 'Todo List', home: new TodoList());
  }
}
```

I have created a class for a list item which is called `Task`:

```
class Task {
  String name;
  int number;

  Task(this.name, this.number);
}
```

The list widget looks like this:

```
class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new TodoListState();
}
```

The `TodoListState` class has a method which adds new items to the list:

```
class TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  List<Task> _todoItems = [];
  List<bool> checkedItems = []; // this was created for testing purposes

  void _addTodoItem(Task task) {
    if (task.name.length > 0) {
      setState(() => checkedItems.add(false)); // works fine
      setState(() => _todoItems.add(new Task('abc', 12))); // does not work
    }
  }
...
}
```

Why when `_addTodoItem` method is called, one item is added to the checkedItems list but `_todoItems` list is left unchanged? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's working as it should, `setState` is only called ***once***, hence the first method is executed. You should add both methods in the `setState` method, since it's called once per run or state, you can write it like this:

```
....
 setState(() => {  
      checkedItems.add(false);
      _todoItems.add(new Task('abc', 12); 
      }); 
....
```

Comment: it works fine with two setState's when _todoItems is converted into for example List<String>: `setState(() => checkedItems.add(false)); setState(() => _todoItems.add('abc'));` Also, leaving only one setState does not solve the issue. I believe the issue is caused that the Task class needs to be somehow extended or that some '@override's are missing.